# Почему не работает Retrofit?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть сайт, который содержит в себе json. Я хочу распарсить, но ничего не выходит. Вот сайт: https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts

MainActivity.java:

```
package org.myapp.retrofittest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView text;
    Link link;
    String url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/";
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = findViewById(R.id.text);
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        link = retrofit.create(Link.class);
        link.getSongs().enqueue(new Callback<GetData>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetData> call,
                                   Response<GetData> response) {
                int id = response.body().getId();
                text.setText(String.valueOf(id));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetData> call, Throwable t) {
                text.setText("Fail");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

GetData.java:

```
package org.myapp.retrofittest;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class GetData {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Link.java(Interface):

```
package org.myapp.retrofittest;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface Link {
    @GET("demo/posts/")
    Call<GetData> getSongs();
}
```

Comment: Всегда прикладывайте логи к вопросу. Всегда выводите сообщения об ошибках в логи. Ошибка у вас в `onFailure` метод приходит. Выведите её в логи и прикрепите текст из логов в вопрос. А проблема у вас из-за того, что в JSON массив, а парсите вы объект. Смените тип на `List<GetData>` в методе `getSongs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разумеется, потому что невозможно преобразовать массив объектов в объект. Возвращаемое значение интерфейса у вас GetData, в то время как сервер возвращает массив GetData.Измените интерфейс так, как описано ниже

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface Link {
    @GET("demo/posts/")
    Call<List<GetData>> getSongs();
}
```