# Какой тип данных использовать для парсинга запросов Retrofit?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть [сайт](https://api.xn--41a.ws/api.php?method=search&q=%D0%91%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&key=5d2ef46e867df7gagsa8bd5708a&v=3), с которого я с помощью retrofit делаю парсинг данных. С помощью [конвертера](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) я получил класс, который соответствует структуре данных одной песни. Когда пытаюсь использовать List, то он пишет:

```
/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 3 path $[0].
```

Код:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText input;
    Link link;
    String url = "https://api.xn--41a.ws/";
    Retrofit retrofit;
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.text);
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        link = retrofit.create(Link.class);

                link.getSongs("Sting").enqueue(new Callback<List<GetSong>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<GetSong>> call, Response<List<GetSong>> response) {
                        txt.setText("good");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<GetSong>> call, Throwable t) {
                        txt.setText("Fail");
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

GetSong.java:

```
public class GetSong {

    @SerializedName("audio_id")
    @Expose
    private String audioId;
    @SerializedName("artist")
    @Expose
    private String artist;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("mp3")
    @Expose
    private String mp3;
    @SerializedName("duration")
    @Expose
    private Integer duration;
    @SerializedName("img")
    @Expose
    private String img;
    @SerializedName("hash")
    @Expose
    private String hash;

    public String getAudioId() {
        return audioId;
    }

    public void setAudioId(String audioId) {
        this.audioId = audioId;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getMp3() {
        return mp3;
    }

    public void setMp3(String mp3) {
        this.mp3 = mp3;
    }

    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

}
```

Link.java:

```
public interface Link {
    @GET("api.php?method=search&key=sadasdashuyandok&v=3")
    Call<List<GetSong>> getSongs(@Query("q") String text);
}
```

Comment: Вы шутите чтоли?  я отвечал вам точно на такой же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112648/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-retrofit/1112662#1112662

Comment: Разница в том, что там вы пытались массив впихнуть в объект, а здесь наоборот - объект в массив, на что указывает ошибка : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY. уберите лист из интерфейса Call<GetSong> и попробуйте не просто вслепую переписывать готовые решения, а еще разбираться в том, как это работает и почему

Comment: Ну дак, я понимаю, что такое класс Song, ибо это объектное представление песни. Чтоб получить песни нужен массив. Нужно ли всё-таки сделать класс с массивом или листом?

Comment: Для сериализатора не имеет значение лист или массив. есть лишь разница между объектом и набором объектов. последний и является массивом либо коллекцией на ваше усмотрение

Comment: Что же тогда делать? Прошу помочь, ибо я в ретрофите 0.

Comment: для начала ваш интерфейс типизирован классом GetSong, а вы в своем вопросе выложили класс Song. у вас класс GetSong вообще существует?

Comment: GetSong и есть Sоng. Не знаю почему скинул Song. Ошибся. Но, это мелочи

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас этот запрос возвращает не просто массив объектов GetSong , а массив, содержащий массив объектов GetSong  и объект с указание айди автора. Боюсь, что для такой структуры вам нужен кастомный десериализатор. посмотрите на сам джайсон, он начинается с 2 квадратных скобок, т.е. массив вложен в массив

Comment: @РоманРемесло ваша правка, увы, не сможет скрыть приватный ключ. Дело в том, что в сообществе StackOverflow сохраняется (и полностью доступна) история редактирования от самых старых версий и со всеми промежуточными. Настоятельно рекомендую сменить приватный ключ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Учитывая мой последний комментарий, вот вам ответ на вопрос. Кастомный десериализатор никто не отменял (писать его вам придется самостоятельно), я предоставлю вам ссылку на пример такого решения,  однако, данный код тоже будет работать (хотя и не без костылей), при этом надеюсь он объяснит вам суть проблемы.
Вот ссылка, почитайте, как правильно решаются такие проблемы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639018/java-parse-json-with-array-with-different-object-types-gson-or-jackson-or-etc
И, разумеется,код:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Test {

    private static String url = "https://api.xn--41a.ws/";
    private final static Type TYPE = new TypeToken<List<GetSong>>(){}.getType();
    private final static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Link link = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(Link.class);
        Object obj = link.getSongs("").execute().body().get(0);
        List<GetSong> result = GSON.fromJson(GSON.toJson(obj), TYPE);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}

import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface Link {
    @GET("api.php?method=search&key=gasigasgiaugsaiuasaAi&v=3")
    Call<List> getSongs(@Query("q") String text);
}
```